# Invalid characters for python output file

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have this little script:

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial as spt

X= np.loadtxt('edm')
myfile = open('edm.txt','w')

V= spt.distance.pdist(X.T,'sqeuclidean')
P = spt.distance.squareform(V)  
print P
myfile.write(P)
```

And this matrix:

```
           0  199.778354301   
201.857546133 0
```

If I run my program; I get this in the terminal (according to the "print"):

```
[[     0.          80657.85977805]
 [ 80657.85977805      0.        ]]
```

But in my output file; I get invalid characters as following :

```
��������z°¶¡±Û@z°¶¡±Û@��������
```

Do you know why?
Thanks

Comment: `print` calls `str(P)` to get a text representation of `P`. `file.write` simply expects `P` to be a character buffer object, which means the byte string that `P` supplies to `file.write` is not necessarily the same that `str(P)` returns.

Comment: OK. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) `savetxt` method to save arrays and not worry about codification.

As in the Docs,

```
>>> np.savetxt('edm.txt', x)   # x is an array
```

Answer (score 1):

The file contains the binary representation of the numbers in the matrix.

```
$ od -t x1z edm.txt 
0000000 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 79 a1 a6 c1 1d b1 f3 40  ........y......@
0000020 79 a1 a6 c1 1d b1 f3 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  y......@........
0000040
```